# How would you go about modeling this cosmetics packaging?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Ever start modelling an object that you think will be fairly simple but then you end up going down about 8 different paths trying to get an accurate shape but for one reason or another your mesh ends up crashing into wall of bad shading and unnecessary geometry?

That's me right now - I'm trying to model the pump cap section of this bottle - I've been down the subdiv route, boolean route, 2 object and loft route etc, but no matter what i end up with too much geometry and about 50 support loops.

What would your approach be for a mesh like this? My sincere thanks in advance.

[image: back ortho]
[image: side ortho]
[image: top ortho]
[image: front ortho]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with a cube that you subdivide (*Number of Cuts* > 3, *Smoothness* > 1):

[image]

Cut off the bottom, extrude down, mirror with a modifier:

[image]

Extrude and scale to create the beak:

[image]

Inset the top faces (press <kbd>B</kbd> for *Boundary* so that the new faces stick to the mirror axis):

[image]

Work the topology to sharp some edges:

[image]

You should be able to get something like that:

[image]

Comment: ABSOLUTE HERO OF A LEGEND